# java Refactoring if else

Tags: java, if-statement, coding-efficiency

I have this if else code, I was wondering if there is more useful/intelligent way for writing it :

```
public void saveContent() throws Exception {
   if(book.isColored()) {
      book.setChoosen(“1234”);
   } else if (book.isAvailable()) {
      book.setChosen(“23498”);
   } else if (book.isAdults()) {
      book.setChosen(“0562”);
   } else {
      ReaderResponse response = reader.getReaderResponse();
      if (response != null) {
         book.setChosen(response.getName());
         }
      } else {
            book.setChosen(“4587”);
      }
   }
}
```

The method returns void.

Comment: well , switch could be better

Comment: @parladneupane how do you use switch on different attributes?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but this may be more on topic on CodeReview

Comment: You could use inheritance, with overwritten setChosen() for each kind of book.

Comment: Just out of interest: Can't a book be colored, available and adult-only? We have available, colored adult-only books in my country.

Comment: @deHaar apparently not :v

Comment: If those booleans are exclusive, then it could be a single value with an enum, and therefore a switch.  From their names, they don't sound as if they are, which makes me wonder if your if else code really makes a lot of sense.  I mean, you care about whether or not the book is available only if it is not colored?

Comment: You could use a List<Pair<Predicate, Function>>. Find the first predicate that's true and apply the function.

Comment: As written, this wouldn't even compile. Your braces are messed up, and your last `else` is not attached to any `if`.

Comment: @jhamon, i agree with Zag statement

Comment: This is fine if it does what it's supposed to do.  Is there a more useful way?  Useful for what? Probably not.  More intelligent way?  If you mean a more *clever* way, then sure there is, but it's better not to be clever without a good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say this is more efficient, more useful or smarter way of doing the same, but certainly I think the code will be cleaner and testable by delegating the actual choosen code resolution to a different method:

```
public void saveContent() throws Exception {
   String choosenCode = getChoosenCode(book);
   book.setChoosen(choosenCode);
}

static String getChoosenCode(Book book) throws Exception {
   if (book.isColored()) {
      return “1234”;
   }
   if (book.isAvailable()) {
      return “23498”;
   }
   if (book.isAdults()) {
      return “0562”;
   }
   ReaderResponse response = reader.getReaderResponse();
   return (response != null) 
      ? response.getName()
      : “4587”;
}
```

As you can see there is no need of endless if-else blocks because of the early return approach. This also provides the ability to unit-test the choosen code part, which is a little more complicated if you have a `void` returning method.

Answer (score 5):

The introduction of a local variable in the middle of this causes problems. One way of dealing this is introducing another method - don't be afraid of small methods.

```
public void saveContent() throws Exception {
    book.setChoosen(
        book.isColored()   ? “1234"  :
        book.isAvailable() ? “23498” :
        book.isAdults()    ? “0562”  :
        readerResponse()
    );
}
private String readerResponse() throws Exception {
    ReaderResponse response = reader.getReaderResponse();
    return response == null ? “4587” : response.getName();
}
```

`?` `:` is the conditional operator, often referred to as the ternary operator.

In the event that `getReaderResponse` has no side-effect, you could repeat the call. `get` methods *typically* do not have side-effects, but I get the feeling here this one may well do. I am not sure where the `Exception` is thrown - I assume that is intended to be replace with a subtype.

Comment: Very nice. How about `Optional.ofNullable(reader.getReaderResponse).map(r -> r.getName()).orElse("4587")`?

Comment: Not at all, just wanted to suggest. Your "long" way might indeed be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement Strategy Design Pattern as an alternative to if-else construction

Comment: I tend to like Strategy Pattern a lot. Don't you think it will be overkill for such a simple case ?

Comment: Maybe you're right, but strategy bases on lightweight classes. It will not have much impact.

Answer (score 0):

Switch statement wouldn't help, because you're checking different kind of attributes. I'd use `if statements` but instead of "magical numbers" I'd use some `static final` constants. And I'd remove inside of last `else` statement into a separate method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a issue i´m thinking about for months. In my opinion it is not easy to write that code in a way it is smart and reabable for non senior programmers. A good way would be using a switch-statement, but this is not useable for boolean statements.

I would use the code as mentioned in the questions, but i´d move it to a single class/controller/service for more complex code (this would be better for testing complex behaviours).

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add a Stream version, but I do not consider it adequate for just a handfull of cases.

```
List<Pair<Predicate<Book>, String>> mapping;
mapping.add(Book::isColored, "1234");
mapping.add(Book::isAvailable, "23498");
mapping.add(Book::isAdults, "0562");
ReaderResponse response = reader.getReaderResponse();
mapping.add((anyBook) -> response == null, "4587");

String chosen = mapping.stream()
        .filter(p -> p.getKey().test(book))
        .map(Pair::getValue)
        .findFirst()
        .orElseGet(response::getName);
```

Or

```
mapping.add((anyBook) -> true, response.getName());
mapping.stream()
        .filter(p -> p.getKey().test(book))
        .map(Pair::getValue)
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(book::setChose);
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't implement your algorithm *exactly* (because there are some ambiguities) but demonstrates using an `enum` as a strategy pattern. In this form it is much easier to add/adjust the code because all special functionality of each book type is in it's own location (it's own `enum`).

Note that this also helps when a book can fall into several types (such as `Coloured` **and** `Adult`).

```
enum BookType {
    Coloured("1234"),
    Available("23498"),
    Adult("0562");

    private final String chosen;

    BookType(String chosen) {
        this.chosen = chosen;
    }

    public String getChosen() {
        return chosen;
    }

}

class Book {
    final Set<BookType> types = EnumSet.noneOf(BookType.class);
    Book book;

    public boolean hasType(BookType type) {
        return types.contains(type);
    }

    public void setChosen(String s) {

    }
}

public void saveContent() throws Exception {
    for(BookType type: BookType.values()) {
        if(book.hasType(type)) {
            book.setChosen(type.getChosen());
        }
    }
}
```